# Restful web service with Jersey 2.0

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

Can anybody tell me how to make a restful web service with Jersey 2.0. I have searched everywhere and found tutorial for Jersey1.x versions but not for 2.0. Please help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In jersey 2.0 they have changed the servlet container class

```
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>

      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>

      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>

      <param-value>com.MyApplication</param-value>

    </init-param>



import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;


public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        packages("com.rest");
    }
}
```

Other things are same as jersey 1.0

Comment: where sholud i place MyApplication inside com package

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/
Refer this link.For web.xml refer my code.Rest changes are same
com.rest will be the package where your service present

Comment: I am not using maven. And I made these changes in web.xml and created MyApplication.java in com package. I am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.MyApplication exception on running my application

Comment: Give fully qualified name of MyApplication in web.xml file.Skip maven configuration.Deploy webservice in your server and run it

Comment: tomcat gives error MyApplication not found

Comment: what exception it is giving

Comment: Thank you it worked perfecly. I skipped 1 jar that's why error was there.

Comment: @MayurB Why do I need the declaration of Application ?can't I use com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages?

Comment: @Dejel There are multiple ways to declare the Service class.You can specify com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages also.It look your sevice in specific package.

Answer (score 2):

check out the [Offical Jersey User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html)

there is a section called **List of Examples**

Answer (score 1):

See the Java EE 7 Tutorial, especially the section [Building RESTful Web Services with JAX-RS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs.htm). There is a [Jersey Tutorial](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html), too.

Answer (score 1):

Sample project is there in the link https://github.com/aruld/jersey2-sample

Comment: I am not able to run the project from eclipse.

Comment: Also i need to run the application on tomcat